# Get next row of cursor in a loop without moving the index of cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on Oracle procedure where I have to calculate time difference  between two rows
time is present as column in cursor.
For this I will have to loop over a cursor and get the current row and next row and calculate the time difference.
How can I do this in loop ?
How can I get the next row cursor without moving a cursor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If time is present in column in cursor then you can add one more column in the cursor and use `lead` to fill next row Time as follows:

```
-- YOUR CURSOR QUERY EXAMPLE
SELECT COL1, TIME_COL FROM .....

--yOU NEED TO ADD ONE MORE COLUMN
SELECT COL1, TIME_COL, LEAD(TIME_COL) OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) FROM ...
```

You can learn more about LEAD from some [good source](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-lead/)

Comment: Yes.. Thats what I need 
I was confused on how to use lead in my case but link you provided made it clear
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to use analytic functions n lag(col) over(order by... ) or lead(col) over(order by...)